# Basic question on logic substitution

Tags: functions, logic, first-order-logic

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_(logic)) explains that substitution is a function $\sigma : V \rightarrow T$ that maps all variables $x_i$ to the corresponding term $t_i$ for some natural number $i$. Additionaly, according to the article, some authors state that $\sigma(x)=x$. What does that mean? That the substitution function $\sigma$ is an identity function, in which every replaced variable $x$ is equal to the replacing term $\sigma(x)$? That interpretation does not seem quite right for me, since some paragraphs later, the text talks about invertible and not invertible substitution functions. If the substitution function $\sigma$ is an identity function, then, if $card(T) \leq card(V)$, $\sigma$ is surjective and injective and, hence, always invertible.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by some of the wording in the Wikipedia article, so I'm not posting this as an answer.  However, I think the statement that $\sigma(x)=x$ for all but finitely many variables means that a substitution function may be such that it doesn't have to replace all of the variables with terms.  Instead, it might leave many of the variables unchanged, as variables.  e.g. $\sigma(x \& y)=(\mbox{true}\; \&\; y)$ is a possible mapping.

Comment: Thank you, Mars. I thought the same initially, but at the end of the sentence, the text says that the function maps "every other [not replaced] variable to itself". That's is actually an identity mapping, as far as I understood.

Comment: Example: given the formula $P(x, y)$ and the substitution formula $\sigma = \{ x \rightarrow a \}$, the resulting term would be $P(a, y)$. As in your example, $y$ was left unchanged, so that means $y$ is mapped to itself in $\sigma$, so that $\sigma = \{ x \rightarrow a, y \rightarrow y \}$. Since $x=a$ in the substitution instance $P(a, y)$, $\sigma$ is an identity function. However, I must say that I not sure even a bit if this interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full quote from that paragraph of Wikipedia for reference

> In first-order logic, a **substitution** is a total mapping $\sigma : V \to T$ from variables to terms; many, but not all, authors
> additionally require that $\sigma(x) = x$ for all but finitely many
> variables $x$.

This means that $\sigma$ leaves all but finitely many variables the same when transforming one well-formed formula into another. "$\sigma(x)=x$" is not meant to imply that all variables $x$ are sent to themselves by $\sigma$, but rather that some of them (specifically cofinitely many) are.

The idea here is that a substitution, when written in the set of pairs notation shown below with fixed points omitted, should be finite.

$$ \{ (x_1, t_1), (x_2, t_2), \cdots ,(x_7, t_7) \} \;\; \text{completely describes $\sigma$ and is finite} $$

We could have chosen to define $\sigma$ differently, with a domain of $V'$, a finite subset of $V$. In that case, $\sigma$ when applied to a formula would only replace variables in $V'$. Variables in $V\setminus V'$ would be untouched.

Comment: So, $\sigma (x)=x$ applies only to those variables in $V\V'$ that remain the same in the substitution instance. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Everything in the domain of $\sigma$ that is not in $V'$ (which is finite) is a fixed point of $\sigma$. The Wikipedia article is careful to say that some authors impose this restriction on valid substitutions and others don't.